# Smart cast to 'ListViewModel' is impossible, because 'binding.listViewModel' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making a small tasker for android with kotlin. I divided the main activity in some fragments and then created a ViewModel for each one. But now here appeared an issue with smart cast.

Here is some code:

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val binding: FragmentListBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

        val dataSource = TaskDatabase.getInstance(application).taskDatabaseDao

        val viewModelFactory = ListViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)

        val listViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ListViewModel::class.java)

        binding.listViewModel = listViewModel

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        binding.addButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_createTaskFragment)
        }

        binding.listViewModel.tasks.observe(this, Observer {
            it?.forEach {
                Log.i("ListFragment", "tasks exist")
                val radioButton = RadioButton(context)
                radioButton.text = it.title
                radioButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        })

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

```
class ListViewModel(
    val database: TaskDao,
    application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val viewModelJob = Job()

    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    private val _tasks = MutableLiveData<List<Task>>()
    val tasks: LiveData<List<Task>>
        get() = _tasks

    init {
        initializeTasks()
    }

    private fun initializeTasks() {
        uiScope.launch {
            _tasks.value = getTasksFromDatabase()?.value
            Log.i("ListViewModel", "something")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getTasksFromDatabase(): LiveData<List<Task>>? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            database.getAllTasks()
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

I had expected to see some created radioButtons on the main screen in help of observer method, but instead I got an exception which is mentioned in the title of this question. Thank for your help in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using

```
binding.listViewModel.tasks.observe(this, Observer {
```

Just use the `listViewModel` variable you already have:

```
listViewModel.tasks.observe(this, Observer {
```

This works because your `listViewModel` is a `val` - i.e., an immutable, never null variable. This differs from `binding.listViewModel` which is a mutable, nullable variable - while you know it is not null since you called `binding.listViewModel = listViewModel`, the compiler does not know if there was some other thread that set it back to null.

Comment: I have already tried this variant but it did not work, or it does not depend on this issue?

Comment: What do you mean "it did not work"? Can you include the full error message in your question when you use the `listViewModel` object directly?

Comment: There was no stack trace, actually. I mean, that after ViewModel initialisation my program gets all entities from the database(you can see it in ViewModel class) and set them to MutableLiveData variable `_tasks`. And then `listViewModel` observer in `ListFragment` has to show this info in UI by creating some radioButtons, but for now it does not do this.

Comment: Great, so the problem in this question is solved with no more error messages and your Observer gets called correctly. It seems like your next problem (namely that you create radio buttons but never add them to a layout or handle multiple calls to your Observer correctly) should be handled as a separate question